# Postgres Tuple concurrently updated during dynamic Revoke

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am trying to revoke all the dependencies(several hundreds) of a set of Postgres roles before dropping the role.

I was executing the below script.

```
do
$$
declare
rec record;
begin
for rec in 
select distinct u.table_schema, u.table_name, r.rolname
from pg_roles r join information_schema.role_table_grants u
on r.rolname = u.grantee
where (r.rolname ilike '%mentor%')
LOOP
execute concat('REVOKE ALL ON ', rec.table_schema, '.', rec.table_name, ' FROM ', rec.rolname);
END LOOP;
end;
$$;
```

It worked just fine for one set of roles, but when I tried for another set of roles(that has 'mentor' in its name) it was throwing the below error.

```
ERROR: tuple concurrently updated
CONTEXT: SQL statement "REVOKE ALL ON schema_main.tab_gtl_ltrs from mentor_1"
PL/plSQL function inline_code_block line 106 at EXECUTE
```

Can someone help on how to resolve this? I'm aware that this type of error for DML statements can be resolved by locking the rows by using `'FOR'` statement. But I am not able to find the solution for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible workaround was to use `REASSIGN OWNED BY` and `DROP OWNED` by to resolve this issue.

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY mentor_1 TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY mentor_1;
DROP ROLE mentor_1;
```